# In scala macros, how to get the complete `extends` clause for a class?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Given

```
trait A[T]
class B[T] extends A[Option[T]]
```

In a macro, I can see that `A` is a supertype of `B` and `B` is a subtype of `A`, but the specifics of how the type parameters match up is missing.

How can I get the complete `extends A[Option[T]]` information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want this info given the type, not the tree (which is quite a bit easier, but less general). The trick is to use `baseType` to get the type instance of `A` that's a super-type of your `B`, and then to pull out its type parameters by matching with `TypeRef`:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

def whateverImpl[X: c.WeakTypeTag, Y: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context) = {
  import c.universe._

  val xSymbol = weakTypeOf[X].typeSymbol
  val ySymbol = weakTypeOf[Y].typeSymbol

  ySymbol.typeSignature.baseType(xSymbol) match {
    case TypeRef(_, _, List(arg)) => println(arg)
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Types don't work.")
  }

  q"()"
}

def whatever[X, Y]: Unit = macro whateverImpl[X, Y]

trait A[T]
class B[T] extends A[Option[T]]
```

And then:

```
scala> whatever[A[_], B[_]]
Option[T]
```

This can easily be adapted for 2.10 by removing the `whitebox` part.